# how python test binary data inside some plain text which was extract from database

Tags: python, mysql, binary

I have to extract some product information from mysql database, then construct a `SOAP` request and use python's suds library to send this `SOAP` request to a remote server.

But some of the information extract is combine with binary data and text data, such as:

```
...
Some plain data
...
Content-Type: image/pjpeg

? JFIF  H H   C 


 C     
  P P                  E       !1AQa "q?#2脑$4BCR倯ご?3TVfrs枴贬             -        !1A"2QR亼Ba毖q?   ? 鮊€
 ( ?€
 ( ?€
 釱Whf颲[e?喸媼q屧ㄠ蚀厲蹳ZIO痙(r5?-i擯栧剗矹?尴?蝓玁帰XZ鞭#崛攳┸蹵X僦?攅Z@?らM;X藙?N蹮垀s@jQ?Z徸林炑M~?麒]H=颦C胝_р}"?Gixqz坽徸玨?O?Q+谍?w鬪??-囯礥?а|乛聚Zyt>?`[~跲桫?騽D曐縅CmN=?shOU+湫锏竩&6げ?铚扺d)mn?c?X?6RmQ   JJ?7繴*v>.捈鉵基d?堌疻熼G肗裪囅w騲癔R?qW鑪陭瞘.C窄贇CkyV瀷1? 柚%W}}?Yz僫芐D嫆1鬊懜赈篽效lq蒟H棯]y|G.;硅憖Ew??栧$?=e菚鏪Rbj?枝}爲釼Z3FE<尒n%C蓎??樋>`I 顝y∥+pP敐慗岻゛\硳诮湣]~??xΔ诩[_?叴b嫜?yz*?=ψk?猝"%Ak?撍滷秠BR?-铈b礖?蟷y[)厌麓4,怈
窧q觏?_   N獛擒F杍q凞画Q襃@镛P$讄k\鏁祘譟㎎*V>W??鵔M嫯q寓y焊閔C杔栽?+鹕瑟qbs:z氱^PJ聣?汜ZU"ス嘔+輔€8楺<夻Uゎ顓瞚?氅豴<]P銨c? +K6]┓gr杺  蝫?VJ能?陭欹殡J倢gS扚?娭酧??gw?膙y矼j折B礕殯
繅捁%撽蛵震挔撲y?3鑪澳N?Ec~涰巽j慭搆锥▓IP?)┤燎鐠懴 €H9瘾F毖l氾+岎6o?殎託炗y尬n??8??黬?4Qbń覦;縢?兟HRONd *紂蚽娖t猦?^?2
庴E$x 譴q箘瘃J檐H筶鷆[?8 ?9颢*髟揤v緜魸擭槧?%msV嬖z瘨摉擀F摫鞍s犮殩H4s咸?S蓉扷濅?    V?昋c?u婆SG撙???{臘亞攕曳<\K? D]+#瓃kgw犤?.?惨邔蹓#p(巂s?瘑蜲Q?傻鑟6ce?敟)?9嶔?測誗?yfvp謒NnbmB3齑栘v>RR=拏H'焴j壎e鎨洘?窑??MH单;5?T1倧o)锐认J?QY&7?橥%诤授b?氭\堫轁q)荖no弎閂?添頶5E敌?U瞿??雛柖Q??Ps?冇9'=)J殅朥k%鈌l疆$q}?い$袋蜕~跏綺衄qU玉矰潱v硻e鷵?薭?<爗树q熣?I;ぞ_鬿埗d.握莰俜6渺^貀No-乾R?r\芷<A稙鋆j璲吡累Y错$F梱?镫[猄k\﹋JrRp悇?救 
...
end of binary data.
```

I don't know how this data insert into mysql, but I have to detect this type  of data, and replace this binary data to string `EEEEE`, otherwise suds will raise exception.

Anyone can tell me how to test this type of data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixed text and binary?! Sounds awful...

However if all data is in the format you presented in your example (i.e. with a `Content-type` declaration) you could do something along the lines of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8  -*-

data = '''Some plain data!Content-Type: image/pjpeg ? JFIF  H H   C  C 
          P P                  E       !1AQa "q?#2脑$4BCR倯ご?3TVfrs枴贬    - 釱W
          hf颲[e?喸媼q屧ㄠ蚀厲蹳ZIO痙(r5?-i擯栧剗矹?尴?蝓玁帰XZ鞭#崛攳┸蹵X僦?攅Z@?らM
          ;X藙?N蹮垀s@jQ?Z徸林炑M~?麒]H=颦C胝_р}"?Gixqz坽徸玨?O?Q+谍?w鬪??'''
tdata = '''This has no binary in it'''

def filter_data(blob):
    mixed = blob.find('Content-Type:')
    if mixed != -1:  # -1 ==> not found
        return blob[:mixed] + 'EEEEE'
    return blob

print filter_data(data)
print filter_data(tdata)
```

If binary data is not prepended by a `Content-Type` declaration, I'm not sure there is a **100% reliable** way to distinguish text from binary (a byte from the binary could be decoded to some sensful character) but you could at least improve the situation by filtering against a pool of valid characters.

For example, assuming that all valid text is alphanumeric A-Z, a-z and 0-1 plus the space character:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8  -*-

data = '''Some plain data脑$4BCR倯ご?3TVfrs枴贬    - 釱W hf颲[e?喸媼q屧ㄠ蚀厲蹳
          ZIO痙(r5?-i擯栧剗矹?尴?蝓玁帰XZ鞭#崛攳┸蹵X僦?攅Z@?らM;X藙?N蹮垀s@jQ?Z徸
          林炑M~?麒]H=颦C胝_р}"?Gixqz坽徸玨?O?Q+谍?w鬪??'''
tdata = '''This has no binary in it'''
bdata = '''炑M~?麒]H=颦C胝'''

pool = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 '

def filter_data(blob):
    last_good_one = None
    for i, c in enumerate(blob):
        if c in pool:
            last_good_one = i
        else:
            break
    if last_good_one == None:
        raise BaseException('Only binary data!')
    return blob[:last_good_one+1]

print filter_data(data)
print filter_data(tdata)
print filter_data(bdata)
```

HTH!

Comment: thank you:) Now I just need to find what's the charset a http request body could be.